# Implement toString() method in Groovy to list data from database

Tags: postgresql, groovy, jira-plugin

I am trying to get a `toString()` method working so I can list everything from the database. But I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong. I am using Groovy in a script console, which does not let me use `println`. All I can do is collect all output and return as a string

```
return getUserId()
@ToString
class Logs{
                    String created = ""
                    String summary =""
                    String category =""
                    String searchField =""
}

def getUserId(){
        def driver = Class.forName('org.postgresql.Driver').newInstance() as Driver
        def props = new Properties()

    props.setProperty("user", "USERNAME")
    props.setProperty("password", "PASSWORD")
    props.setProperty("sslfactory", "org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory")
    props.setProperty("ssl", "true")

    def conn = driver.connect("jdbc:postgresql://Database:port/GRP", props)
    def sql = new Sql(conn)

    try {


            def logs = new Logs(created: 'created', summary: 'summary', category: 'category', searchField: 'searchField')

            String query = "SELECT * from audit_log"

            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query)

            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery()
            while(result.next()){
                    String created1 = result.getString("created")
                    logs.created = created1

                    String summary1 = result.getString("summary")
                    logs.summary = summary1

                    String category1 = result.getString("category")
                    logs.category = catergory1

                    String searchField1 = result.getString("search_field")
                    logs.searchField = searchField1


            }
            return (logs.toString())
    } finally {
        sql.close()
        conn.close()
    }
```

}

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: created for class: Script321
>       at Script321.getUserId(Script321.groovy:100)
>       at Script321.run(Script321.groovy:76)
>
> Line 100 is the: def logs = new Logs((created)+"-" +(summary)+", " +(category)+", " +(searchField))
>
> Line 76 is the: return getUserID()

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because you're trying to define the class `Logs` within the method `getUserId()`. You can fix it by defining the class outside of the method.

```
@ToString
class Logs {
    String created = ""
    String summary =""
    String category =""
    String searchField =""
}

def getUserId(){
    def driver = Class.forName('org.postgresql.Driver').newInstance() as Driver
    def props = new Properties()

    props.setProperty("user", "USERNAME")
    props.setProperty("password", "PASSWORD")
    props.setProperty("sslfactory", "org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory")
    props.setProperty("ssl", "true")
    def conn = driver.connect("jdbc:postgresql://SERVER:PORT/DATABASE", props)
    def sql = new Sql(conn)

    try {
        def logs = new Logs("[GRP2.0] " +(created)+"-" +(summary)+", " +(category)+", " +(searchField))

        String query = "SELECT * from audit_log"

        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query)

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery()

        while(result.next()){
            String created1 = result.getString("created")
            logs.created = created1

            String summary1 = result.getString("summary")
            logs.summary = summary1

            String category1 = result.getString("category")
            logs.category = catergory1

            String searchField1 = result.getString("search_field")
            logs.searchField = searchField1
        }
        return (logs.toString())
    } finally {
        sql.close()
        conn.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code, please see above. I had to add a return getUserId() so it won't show null, but when I did there's an error that says "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: created for class: Script321
 at Script321.getUserId(Script321.groovy:100)
 at Script321.run(Script321.groovy:76)" Line 76 is the return getUserID() and line 100 is the def logs = new Logs("[VSOC2.0] " +(created)+"-" +(summary)+", " +(category)+", " +(searchField))

Comment: It's complaining about the `created`, `summary`, and `category` on line 100. Since you don't have variables with such names Groovy tried to look them up as properties, but they don't exist as properties either. Where are you defining them?

Comment: what do you mean by where do I am defining them? The code above is everything I have. Am i not defining it inside the Logs class? What should I do?

Comment: The `Logs` class has those properties, yes. I can't tell what you're trying to do with them. The Map-based constructor syntax goes like this: `def logs = new Logs(created: 'created value', summary: 'summary value', category: 'category value', searchField: 'searchField value')`

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. I have updated the code, please see line 100 above. I put 'created' 'summary' 'category' 'searchField' inside the quotation because the values are stored in it.

Comment: I am trying to get the values stored in  'created' 'summary' 'category' 'searchField' and show it on the screen. Just like how a toString() method works in java

Comment: Oh, I get it now. In that case, you can just use an empty constructor `def logs = new Logs()`. You're assigning values to the properties from the results of `getString()`. The @ToString takes care of the rest.

Comment: great thanks. But how will I be able to see the output? Since I can't use a println?

Comment: How will I be able to implement a toString() method? so it will output all the values that I need?